# How to delete a certain row in Excel?

Tags: c#, .net

I watch a lot of tutorials on how to delete a certain row in Excel.
Please help mo to delete a row in excel using c#.
The fileReader ,FileWriter and Splitter are already working. My only problem now is how to delete a certain row in Excel.

Class Variable

```
     public static string fileName = @".\Contestant.csv";
     public static string[,] contestant;
```

Main Method

```
   List<string> lines = fileReader(fileName);
        while (i < lines.Count)
        {
            string[] temp = stringSplitter(lines[i], new char[] { ',' });
            // a contains how many elements in the array
            a = temp.Count();
            // divides a and plus by 1 to know how many arrays there should be in the 2d array
            d = (a / 2) + 1;
            contestant = new string[a, d];
```

This is my code for FileReader

```
  static List<string> fileReader(string filePath)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string line = "";

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Message: Please close the file and try again");
            //Console.WriteLine(e); for more detailed errors
        }
        return lines;
    }
```

Here's my code for FileWriter

```
   static void fileWriter(string filePath, bool appendFlag, string message)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(filePath, appendFlag))
        {
            sr.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
```

This is for Splitter String

```
    static string[] stringSplitter(string stringToSplit, char[] splitChars)
    {
        return stringToSplit.Split(splitChars);
    }
```

Comment: is the file a csv file or a real excel workbook?

Comment: An Excel file is **a lot** more complicated than what your code seems to be addressing

Comment: @DanielA.White csv file

Comment: @Flydog57 this is giving me a hard time

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to completely manipulate your date inside the lists, then replace the whole document with the new information. So read all -> manipulate -> replace your document with new content.

Also don't forget to close your FileStreams after reading/writing.

Comment: I dont know where to start since my code is fine , I only want to delete a certain row

Comment: Delte it from your List, then write the new document. That way the excel sheet is a visualization of your code. It's cleaner when you don't try to manipulate your endproduct.